# How do I get an html element to update when new data comes in?

Tags: html, caching

So I am taking data from a google spreadsheet cell, and displaying it on  website with html, and an online api tool.

Basically it's the direct link to the google sheet ran through the api link, and outcomes the correct value. The problem is on the webpage it wont update correctly due to cacheing. I believe it is basically not hitting that link when the page is refreshed.

How do I fix this? I have tried everything I could find.

Edit: When I change the value in the google sheet and refresh the page the value is not updated. But when I get on a different browser, it is correct.

Edit #2: When I am testing different code to try and fix this, every time I update the code, add or remove anything and then refresh the page, it updates.

Comment: I don't see it mentioned, so I agree with @Rafael Xavier about sharing the code. Just Javascript is a good guess for me, but I don't know if you're using that. I'm thinking you can use a timer to check the data every few seconds. Ex: `setInterval(function (){/*your data being used*/}, miliseconds);` So at least mentioning what you're using would help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your "problematic" browser's cache and cookies? post part of the code that makes the link request